# Convert "POSIXct" "POSIXt" class to 4 digit military time character

Tags: r, character, posixct

Is there a way to convert a datetime ("POSIXct" "POSIXt") to a 4 digit character string?

```
> class(df$time)
[1] "POSIXct" "POSIXt" 

> head(df$time)
[1] "1899-12-31 00:00:00 UTC" "1899-12-31 00:15:00 UTC" "1899-12-31 00:30:00 UTC"
[4] "1899-12-31 00:45:00 UTC" "1899-12-31 01:00:00 UTC" "1899-12-31 01:15:00 UTC"
```

to...

```
> head(df$time)
[1] "0000" "0015" "0030"
[4] "0045" "0100" "0115"
```

Comment: `format(df$time, '%H%M')`?

Comment: Is this data coming from Excel?

Comment: @IRTFM, yes it is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
sapply(strsplit(as.character(df$time) , " ") , function(x) {
s <- x[[2]]
s <- strsplit(s , ":")
sapply(s , function(x) paste0(x[1],x[2]))
})
```

Comment: I have given dozen of comments and answers here recommend to not use regexps or string tokenization when you can use _proper date and time libraries_ instead.  I stand by them.

Comment: Thanks for your advice , where his question about 4 digit character string i guss he didn't care about time or date class

Comment: For some reason R kept adding 1900 to the new miltime variable. I still don't understand it, but thank you both.

Answer (score 3):

Times that are already parsed as (or constructed) as `POSIXt` objects, ie Datetime objects can be formatted.  Use for example

```
df$mltime <- strftime(df$time, "%H%M")
```

to add such a column to the data.frame yielding

```
$ Rscript answer.R 
                 time mltime
1 1899-12-31 00:00:00   0000
2 1899-12-31 00:15:00   0015
3 1899-12-31 00:30:00   0030
4 1899-12-31 00:45:00   0045
5 1899-12-31 01:00:00   0100
6 1899-12-31 01:15:00   0115
$
```

##### Code

```
df <- data.frame(time = as.POSIXct(c("1899-12-31 00:00:00 UTC", 
                                     "1899-12-31 00:15:00 UTC",
                                     "1899-12-31 00:30:00 UTC",
                                     "1899-12-31 00:45:00 UTC",
                                     "1899-12-31 01:00:00 UTC", 
                                     "1899-12-31 01:15:00 UTC")))

df$mltime <- strftime(df$time, "%H%M") 
print(df)
```

Comment: I think you answer is correct, but there's something wrong with my variable...its hard to show a table here but  00:00:00  is   1900, 00:15:00  is   1915, etc..

Comment: Actually I just realized that I hadn't (formally) parsed the input. Adjusting now.  Try in a few seconds...  It worked because `strftime()` will force an _implicit_ conversion.  But your example started with `POSIXct` and does my answer now.

Comment: Sorry, I still get this weird answer:                                                                                      > head(format(df$time, format = "%H:%M:%S"))
[1] "00:00:00" "00:15:00" "00:30:00" "00:45:00" "01:00:00" "01:15:00"           
                                                                                                                                           > head(strftime(df$time, "%H%M"))
[1] "1900" "1915" "1930" "1945" "2000" "2015"

Comment: Sorry Nate but this is really hard to read. I gave a you a _full working answer_ with complete code, you run other so ...   I assume that you are concerned about the difference in how the hours are printed (even though your comment does not say so hence I am forced to guess) which could be taken care of by timezone arguments.

Comment: Indeed you did, and I still don't know what was going on with my data. I only know Dohamed Desouky's answer solved the problem. Thanks again for your answer.